# Importing libraries to AIDE

Tags: android, mobile, slidingmenu, android-ide

I'm using aide at the moment since my PC is currently gone.

I'm trying to import the SlidingMenu ([Link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)) library but it doesn't seem that AIDE supports in the form of files (projects).

All I have seen of importing libraries is .jar files.
Anyone know if I can import zip files in AIDE? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AIDE, navigate to `AppProjects` and click on "Clone Git Repository here...". Enter `https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu` for the "Repository URL:" and click "Clone". After it's downloaded, open your project that you want to add it to. Click "Project Properties...", then "Add Library Project...". Click "Ok".
Navigate to `SlidingMenu` and long-press the `library` sub-folder. After it's added, use `import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;` in whichever classes you need.